# How to resolve custom cursor(https file) display issue on IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a cursor file on machine 192.168.1.1, because IE must have absolute path of cursor file, so I have to use it as this;

`cursor:url(https://192.168.1.1/images/cur-grab.cur),move;`

Other browsers work fine, except IE.

I use JavaScript to get and set absolute path:

`'cursor:url(' + location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '/images/cur-grab.cur),move;`

Any good solutions?

Comment: https? secure server?

Comment: Yes, but no certification. The browser displays 'Certification error'.

Comment: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-css-cursor-rule--webdesign-9441   This article says you can use relative paths.

Comment: Relative path to the HTML file location, not the css file location.

Comment: Relative path with https doesn't work. Do you think it's SSL security issue?

Comment: Test it out with a relative path on a background image, not just cursor. It could be SSL issue, but I'm no expert on it or IE ( why does anyone use IE anymore ? )